# QML toggle PropertyChanges onclick

Tags: position, toggle, qml

I try to toggle my navigation with a toggle function. I want to change "x" position.

So here is what i got so far. But don't work. I try to use a toggle function to chnage state on click. I set two different state one that the navigation is visible and one that the navigation is hidden.

I get this error "ReferenceError: toggle is not defined"

```
Item {
    id: toggleswitch
    width: 200
    height: 200

    property bool on: false

    function toggle() {
        if (toggleswitch.state == "on")
            toggleswitch.state = "off";
        else
            toggleswitch.state = "on";
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: open
        width: parent.width
        height: 35
        color: "#33000000"

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "open"
            color: "white"
            font.family: "Helvetica"
            font.pixelSize: 25
        }

        MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: toggle() }
    }


    states: [
        State {
            name: "on"
            PropertyChanges { target: navigation; x: 0 }
            PropertyChanges { target: toggleswitch; on: true }
        },
        State {
            name: "off"
            PropertyChanges { target: navigation; x: -300 }
            PropertyChanges { target: toggleswitch; on: false }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is `navigation` here?

Comment: navigation is a rectangle. i want to made something like this http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/. that the rectangle slides in and out.

Answer (score 0):

Some small slider example:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Rectangle {
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        id: slider
        state: "close"
        states: [
            State {
                name: "close"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: slider
                    width: 50
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "open"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: slider
                    width: 360
                }
            }
        ]
        transitions: [
            Transition {

                NumberAnimation {
                    target: slider
                    property: "width"
                    duration: 500
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutBack
                }
            }
        ]

        color: "green"
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (slider.state == "close")
                slider.state = "open";
            else
                slider.state = "close";
        }
    }
}
```

transitions is optional here

Answer (score 0):

You can say to QML which object is your function.

```
Item {
id: toggleswitch
width: 200
height: 200
state: "off"      //INIT YOUR STATE !!
property bool on: false

function toggle() {
    if (toggleswitch.state == "on")
        toggleswitch.state = "off";
    else
        toggleswitch.state = "on";
}

Rectangle {
    id: open
    width: parent.width
    height: 35
    color: "#33000000"

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "open"
        color: "white"
        font.family: "Helvetica"
        font.pixelSize: 25
    }

    MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: toggleswitch.toggle() } //here
}


states: [
    State {
        name: "on"
        PropertyChanges { target: navigation; x: 0 }
        PropertyChanges { target: toggleswitch; on: true }
    },
    State {
        name: "off"
        PropertyChanges { target: navigation; x: -300 }
        PropertyChanges { target: toggleswitch; on: false }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do here is not manipulate the state directly but toggle on the property directly, and bind the states to that property.

To me it feels more readable, semantical and reduce the  coupling between the object and its visual states.

This also has the advantage of having states always coherent with the `on` property and provides a better abstraction. When  using this component you can freely change the `on` property programmatically and the component display will update accordingly.

That's what I would probably end up with :

```
Item {
id: toggleswitch
width: 200
height: 200
property bool on: false

function toggle() {
    on = !on //simpler toggle function
}

Rectangle {
    id: open
    width: parent.width
    height: 35
    color: "#33000000"

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "open"
        color: "white"
        font.family: "Helvetica"
        font.pixelSize: 25
    }

    MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: toggleswitch.toggle() }
}


states: [
    State {
        name: "on"
        when: toggleswith.on
        PropertyChanges { target: navigation; x: 0 }
    },
    State {
        name: "off"
        when: !toggleswith.on
        PropertyChanges { target: navigation; x: -300 }
    }
]
```